# how can i deploy a bpmn file using JBPM 6.3 api and eclipse without KIE-console?

Tags: java, eclipse, drools, jbpm

i tried to deploy a bpmn file usig **JBPM 6.3** api and eclipse ,
but i have some problems !
i don't know how to use and configure Kmodule.xml file in my project.
i will be grateful if someone can help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLxvl.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qncnx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBPM 6 is using Git for synchronization between KIE Server and Eclipse. You can follow below steps.

1) Create Repository , Project from KIE Workbench (web portal on your local). In order to find repository, if you are using jbpm installer they are in the folder /jbpm-installer/repositories/

2) Import repository into your local using url given in Repository structure in (KIE Workbench)

3) Now you can do your changes using Eclipse bpmn plugin and push your changes to KIE Workbeanch using GIT

Hope it will help you